# Getting "7302 - Cannot Create an instance of OLE DB" Error after ACE/ODBC Driver update

Tags: sql-server, odbc, openrowset, msdasql, access-database-engine

We're running SQL Server 2014 with all the latest service packs. Our users heavily rely on OPENROWSET for importing XLSX, CSV and TXT files. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL','DRIVER={MICROSOFT access TEXT DRIVER (*.TXT, *.CSV)};', 'SELECT * FROM F:\IMPORT\MyTable.CSV')
```

The configuration of the drivers/providers worked fine for all users for years. However, to troubleshoot a memory dump issue (occurring once every 2-5 days), it was recommended that we upgrade both the `ACE` (Access Database Engine), as well as `MSDASQL` (SQL ODBC) Drivers.

After the driver upgrade, we noticed that queries with OPENROWSET statements would hang, causing us to restart the SQL server.

We noticed `Allow inprocess` was selected, as corrective measure, we unselected this, which successfully stopped the crashing/hang-ups.

[image]

Although OPENROWSET queries now run fine for me (as an admin user), however every other user that uses Windows Authentication now gets this error message and can't use `OPENROWSET` at all.

```
Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

**Points to mention:**

- This issue happens with all drivers/providers:

  ```
    MSDASQL                     Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
    Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0    Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
    Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0    Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
  ```
- Yes, the users have access to the necessary files/folders.
- I've ensured `Disallow Ad-Hoc Access` is unchecked for all providers.
- Stand-alone SQL logins (non-Windows Authentication) users surprisingly do not have any issues
- We don't have the resources to flip our processes/scripts to ingest data via SSIS packages.
- The registry values reflect EXACT desired provider settings:

[image]

Comment: Do the Windows users have permissions granted to them in Component Services > Computers > (Server Computer) > DCOM Config > MSDAINITIALIZE > Properties > Security?

Comment: Admistrators have Full Access. 
Users have Read-only access.

Should users have FULL access?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this (Thanks @alwaysLearning for pointing me in the right direction)
We had to adjust the security settings in the DCOM configuration:

This Article explains it in great detail!

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/setting-up-linked-servers-with-an-out-of-process-oledb-provider